# Needs some help with an apache mod-rewrite issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've modified my .htaccess file to have the following statement

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=$1 [L,NS]
```

This allows me to use product URL's like this: http://domain.com/product_name

However, when trying to access a file at the same level as index.php, it always calls the RewriteRule above and errors out.

I need to be able to access files like below, but each URL currently attempts to load index.php.
http://domain.com/about.htm
http://domain.com/terms.htm
http://domain.com/robots.txt
etc

Any suggestions on how I can modify my htaccess file to get this to work correctly?

Comment: How will you distinguish files from product names? Will files have an extension like `.htm`?

Comment: Yes, files will have an extension and products will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want files to trump products you could toss in another condition:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=$1 [L,NS]
```

...meaning that only if the requested URI doesn't map to a file should it be treated as a product.

Having files trump products like this isn't terrible unless you plan on having products with names like "something.html" and "dynamic.php" or "lenna.jpg".

Comment: Very Nice! That seems to work!  Are there any performance issues with doing it this way since it needs to check for a file each time when loading a product?